# How do I solve this recurrence equation T(n) = T(n-1)+n^2 using the unfolding method?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, recurrence, space-complexity

I try to solve this equations:

> **T(n) = T(n-1) + n^2  for n>1**

> **T(1) = 1   for n=1** initial value

knowing that:
**Σ between i=0 and i=n-1 of ^2 = (+1)(2+1)/6**

I proceed as follow:

> T(n-1) = T(n-2) + (n-1)^2

> T(n-2) = T(n-3) + (n-2)^2

> T(n-3) = T(n-4) + (n-3)^2  ecc...

> T(n) = T(n-4) + (n-3)^2 + (n-2)^2 + (n-1)^2 + n^2

> T(n) = T(1) + ... + (n-2)^2 + (n-1)^2 + n^2 =
> = 1 + Σ(n-i)^2 = 1 + Σ(n^2 - 2in +i^2) =    with i between 0 and n-1

> =  1 + n^2 - 2nΣi + Σi^2 =
> =~ 1 + n^2 - 2n*(n-(n-1)+n-(n-2)+...+n-2+n-1) + n(n+1)(2n-1)/6

In the last passage I have changed the Σ with the given one...

> **T(n) =~ 1 + n^2 - 2n(an-b) + (2n^3 + 3n^2 + n)/6  =~  O(n^3)**

Basically I ignore all the negligible powers of **n** but I not sure if this is the legitimate things to do...

Answer (score 2):

When you know that `Σ i^2 for i=0 to i=n-1` equals `(+1)(2+1)/6` you can state that the time complexity in Big O terms is `O(n^3)`.

Since `(+1)(2+1)/6 = (2^3+n^2+2^2+n)/6`, you remove all the constants and lower powers of `n` (yes this is legitimate in Big O calculations as for very large numbers their value will be negligible compared to what the highest power variable produces), and get `O(n^3)`.